# How do I change the iTunes country while maintaining Family Sharing?

Tags: family-sharing

My whole family is moving to different countries. My sister and I are going off to university in Europe and my parents are moving to Southeast Asia. And we are all linked with Family sharing as we share Apple Music.

So how do I change my location on Apple with my parents being in a different country? Can the "child" even be in a different country?

This only thing I can think of doing is getting a new family sharing set up, but I'm still not sure it can allow different countries. 
Should I abandon the Family Sharing altogether?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Family sharing is country-specific. You cannot have accounts in multiple countries in the same "family".

That said, if you don't change the region of your iTunes accounts, nothing will change. Once you change the region of the account, you will only be able to be in a "family" with other members in the same region.